# about http hijacking and keep-alive

Tags: http, go

i use

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
```

get a http.Response, and i want to exactly write to a http handler, but only http.ResponseWriter, so i hijack it.

```
...
webConn, webBuf, err := hj.Hijack()
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
defer webConn.Close()

// Write resp
resp.Write(webBuf)
...
```

Write raw request

But When i hijack, http connection can't reuse (keep-alive), so it slow.

How to solve?

Thanks! Sorry for my pool English.

**update 12/9** 
[image: keepalive]
[image: keepalive2]
keep-alive, It keep two tcp connection, and can reuse.

[image: nokeepalive]
[image: nokeepalive2]
but when i hijack, and conn.Close(), It can't reuse old connection, so it create a new tcp connection when i each refresh.

Comment: Doesn't if it keeps alive depend on what headers you return in the response after your hijack?

Comment: Have you tried not closing the connection? Your questions needs work, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: How did you find out that the hijacked http connection can't reuse (keep-alive)? Are you just reading the header using curl?

Comment: @LarryBattle I screenshot it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use hijack, Because once hijack, the HTTP server library will not do anything else with the connection, So can't reuse.

I change way, copy Header and Body, look like reverse proxy (http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go), Is works.

**Example:**

```
func copyHeader(dst, src http.Header) {
    for k, w := range src {
        for _, v := range w {
            dst.Add(k, v)
        }
    }
}

func copyResponse(r *http.Response, w http.ResponseWriter) {
    copyHeader(w.Header(), r.Header)
    w.WriteHeader(r.StatusCode)
    io.Copy(w, r.Body)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Response) {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://www.example.com")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    copyResponse(resp, w)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem that once the connection is closed the keep-alive connection closes as well.
One possible solution would be to prevent the connection from closing until desired, but I'm not sure if that good advise.

Maybe the correct solution involves creating a instance of [net.TCPConn](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn), copying the connection over it, then calling `.SetKeepAlive(true)`.

Before running the below example, launch another terminal with `netstat -antc | grep 9090`.

Routes in example:

`localhost:9090/ok` is a basic (non-hijacked) connection
`localhost:9090` is a hijacked connection, lasting for 10 seconds.

### Example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func checkError(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

var ka_seconds = 10
var conn_id = 0
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/ok", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "ok")
    })
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        conn_id++
        fmt.Printf("Connection %v: Keep-alive is enabled %v seconds\n", conn_id, ka_seconds)
        hj, ok := w.(http.Hijacker)
        if !ok {
            http.Error(w, "webserver doesn't support hijacking", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        conn, bufrw, err := hj.Hijack()
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        // Don't forget to close the connection:
        time.AfterFunc(time.Second* time.Duration(ka_seconds), func() {
            conn.Close()
            fmt.Printf("Connection %v: Keep-alive is disabled.\n", conn_id)
        })
        resp, err := http.Get("http://www.example.com")
        checkError(err)
        resp.Write(bufrw)
        bufrw.Flush()
    })
    fmt.Println("Listing to localhost:9090")
    http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
}
```

Related issue: http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5645

Comment: I did flush, but `defer conn.Close()` close the web connection, so this connection can't reuse

Comment: @Specode Please provide more code so everyone can better understand the problem. It's hard to tell what you're doing with the hijack connection.

Comment: this only keep connection but can't reuse. so i change way, try look like reverse proxy (http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go), copy header and body, it works. Thanks you very much.