# when to use hijack in golang?

Tags: go, go-http

I don't understand why we use hijack, since I can write something into response body directly, could anyone explain this?

```
func writeSome(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "write some thing")
}
```

it is same as this:

```
func hijack(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    hj, _ := w.(http.Hijacker)
    _, buf, _ := hj.Hijack()
    buf.WriteString("write some thing")
    buf.Flush()
}
```

I am confused

Answer (score 29):

Use Hijack when you don't want to use the built-in server's implementation of the HTTP protocol. This might be because you want to switch protocols (to WebSocket for example) or the built-in server is getting in your way.

The two snippets of code above do not create the same output on the wire. The output from the first snippet will include a response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 26 Nov 2014 03:37:57 GMT
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

write some thing
```

The second snippet bypasses the built-in server code and writes

```
write some thing
```

directly to the output.

Answer (score 7):

You can see one library ([martini](https://github.com/go-martini/martini)) which introduced `hijack`: [issue 45](https://github.com/go-martini/martini/issues/45)
(Note: I don't recommend Martini, [which is not idiomatic](https://web.archive.org/web/20161125163222/https://codegangsta.io/blog/2014/05/19/my-thoughts-on-martini/), but it is mentioned here only to illustrate `hijack`)

> Would it be possible for your responseWriter type to implement http.Hijack?
>   This would allow libraries like this [websockets one](http://godoc.org/github.com/appio/websocket) to work with martini.

That issue refers to the [following go-nuts thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/zq_i3Hf7Nbs), where one tried to embed the interface `http.ResponseWriter` in order to record statistics like bytes written and request duration.

> Later on somebody pointed out some other interesting features of the http library, such as the [`CloseNotifier`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#CloseNotifier) interface, and I realized the above code might not be such a good idea.
>   Since I'm embedding an *interface*, I can't automatically inherit `*http.Response`'s implementations of `CloseNotifier` and `Flusher`.

So, if you want to take over the `ResponseWriter` in order to:

- record more information (status, size, ..., calling hijack is probably overkill here),
- implement another protocol (like websocket, which "[`Upgrade`](http://godoc.org/github.com/appio/websocket#Upgrade)" an HTTP server connection, [calling `w.(http.Hijacker)`](https://github.com/appio/websocket/blob/master/server.go#L72-L87))

Then you can consider using hijack.
But, [as documented](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Hijacker), after a call to `Hijack()`, the HTTP server library will not do anything else with the connection.
It becomes the caller's responsibility to manage and close the connection.

If not, as illustrating [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20393147/6309), then hijack isn't interesting.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest you to use Martini because it is not idiomatic to Go

Comment: @qwertmax I know, and I have edited the answer to make that clear. You can revert your downvote now.

Comment: @qwertmax That is strange: you still have *not* reverted your downvote. Is there something missing?

Comment: Link on ?my thoughts on martini" now links to a bet365 spam, does anybody have the original article?

Comment: @FelipeValdes Thank you. I have restored the link to the article "My Thoughts on Martini"